# Code outside loop being executed during loop

Tags: ios, swift, loops

I'm trying to retrieve the set of images selected by the user in the PHPicker and storing them in an array. I'm iterating the PHPicker results array and appending in each iteration the loaded image to a variable. For some reason, the code that follows this iteration is called before the iteration is finished. I've tried while and for loops, removed DispatchQueue.main.async, nothing seems to change the order of the calls. It's probably very obvious what I'm doing wrong but I really do not get it.

```
var itemProviders: [NSItemProvider] = []
var iterator: IndexingIterator<[NSItemProvider]>?
var images = [UIImage]()


func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true)
    
    itemProviders = results.map(\.itemProvider)
    iterator = itemProviders.makeIterator()
    
    while let itemProvider = iterator?.next(), itemProvider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
        print("\n Entered while")
        itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { image, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let image = image as? UIImage else { return }
                self.images.append(image)
                print("Image: \(image)")
                print("Images: \(self.images)")
            }
        }
    }
    displayAndStoreImages()
}


func displayAndStoreImages(){
    print("\n Entered displayAndStoreImages()")
    print("Images: \(images) \n")
    
    (...)
}
```

This is the result of selecting 2 images in the PHPicker. 2 iterations are executed but not the code inside the iteration block. Instead, the following code is executed and only after this, the code inside the iteration block is called. Why is code outside the loop being executed during the loop? TIA

> ```
>  Entered while
>  Entered while
>
>  Entered displayAndStoreImages()
>  Images: [] 
>
>  Image: <UIImage:0x6000010ec3f0 anonymous {4288, 2848}>
>  Images: [<UIImage:0x6000010ec3f0 anonymous {4288, 2848}>]
>  Image: <UIImage:0x6000010d4630 anonymous {3000, 2002}>
>  Images: [<UIImage:0x6000010ec3f0 anonymous {4288, 2848}>, <UIImage:0x6000010d4630 anonymous {3000, 2002}>]
> ```

Comment: Because you are making asynchronous calls when downloading the images so displayAndStoreImages() gets called before files are downloaded and the closure is executed

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I get the same results without DispatchQueue.main.async, I tried that before posting.

Comment: `itemProvider.loadObject` is an async function... so that's why you get it with/without `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

Comment: @NewDev Thank you for the further clarification, I get it now!

Comment: @NewDev What are the alternatives for a synchronous call? I have been trying several alternatives solutions but nothing seems to work. I just want to retrieve the selected images in original size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of async work you need something like `DispatchGroup`.

Edited your example to take use of it

```
    func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true)
    
    itemProviders = results.map(\.itemProvider)
    iterator = itemProviders.makeIterator()
    
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    
    while let itemProvider = iterator?.next(), itemProvider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {

        dispatchGroup.enter()

        print("\n Entered while")
        itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { image, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let image = image as? UIImage else { return }
                self.images.append(image)
                print("Image: \(image)")
                print("Images: \(self.images)")

                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        }
    }
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        self.displayAndStoreImages()
    }
}


func displayAndStoreImages(){
    print("\n Entered displayAndStoreImages()")
    print("Images: \(images) \n")
    
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! Thanks for your answer, useful to know about dispatchGroup. The solution works but, for some reason, it takes a few seconds between closing the picker and displaying the images.

Comment: The delay is not related to the proposed solution, my fault.